# Silverlight - Client Verification

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that needs to retrieve some data from my database. This data is sensitive. Because of this, I only want my Silverlight application to be able to access the data. How do I ensure that only my applications can access the services that expose this data? Is there a way that I can validate a client attempting to retrieve the data?

Thank you!

Comment: Extrapolating the problem a bit, when your personal username and password is used to log into your laptop or home computer, how does the computer know it's you typing it instead of somebody else? To a high degree it's the same problem you're describing on a different level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might be of interest:

[Using ASP.NET Secure Services and Applications Services](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/using-aspnet-secure-services-and-applications-services/)

[Build Line-Of-Business Enterprise Apps With Silverlight, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434653.aspx)

MS Whitepaper: [Security Guidance for Writing and Deploying Silverlight Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7CEF15A8-8AE6-48EB-9621-EE35C2547773&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Well, everything your SL application does could be spoofed. So direct answer is NO, you cannot ensure that only your application will access to the data.

But there are number of options. For example you can implement authorization and then authenticate your user. In this way you can ensure that only users you trust access to the data.

Another option is to make spoofing harder. For example you can include sort of "secrete" token to all your requests. So other application will need to steal this token. This harder to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is more pertaining into implementing a web service or wcf service with authentication and authorization. If your service takes care of it, then you can be ensured about your data. Your silvelight app is just calling the service.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever download the xap can decompress and reverse engineer your code, so your best bet is to build a web service as others suggested. Silverlight Ria ships with a full blown authentication membership that you can leverage.